# Godot 3.4 issue with AudioStream3D playing random sounds

Tags: godot, audio

I got this problem with an AudioStream3D,  it's supposed to play randomly from a  list of 3 possible sounds when the player fire a gun, but no sound is being played when the event happens.

What i'm doing wrong??

```
  export(String, FILE, "*.wav") var audio_shot_0
    export(String, FILE, "*.wav") var audio_shot_1
    export(String, FILE, "*.wav") var audio_shot_2
    var sound_files = []
    
    func _ready():
        randomize()
        sound_files = [audio_shot_0, audio_shot_1, audio_shot_2]
    
    func fire():
        
        var sound_index = randi() % sound_files.size()
        audio_player.stream = load(sound_files[sound_index])
        audio_player.play()
```

Edit:
Ok, i found out in what was the problem, turns out youhave to enable in the viewport options the AudioListener either 2D or 3D

Comment: During your debugging, have you been able to play at least _one_ of those sounds, like `audio_player.stream = load(audio_shot_0)`?

Comment: no, not any of them

Comment: Did you get any error on output/console/log files?

Comment: no, no error on the console.

Comment: I tested a sample scene using your very code, and it works. Maybe you are just not invoking the `fire()` function as intended?

Comment: ok i tried to make simple scene with similar code to test it, still no sound